# Creating a function in Python that counts number of letters in a dictionary

Tags: python

How do I create a function that will let me input a word, and it will execute to create a dictionary that counts individual letters in the code. I would want it to display as a dictionary, for example, by inputting 'hello' it will display {'e': 1, 'h': 1, 'l': 2, 'o': 1}

I AM ALSO required to have 2 arguments in the function, one for the string and one for the dictionary. THIS IS DIFFERENT to the "Counting each letter's frequency in a string" question.

For example, I think I would have to start as,

```
d = {}
def count(text, d ={}):

    count = 0
    for l in text:
      if l in d:
        count +=1
      else: 
        d.append(l)

    return count
```

But this is incorrect? Also Would i need to set a default value to text, by writing text ="" in case the user does not actually enter any word?

***Furthermore*, if there were existing values already in the dictionary, I want it to add to that existing list. How would this be achieved?**

Also if there were already existing words in the dictionary, then how would you add onto that list, e.g. dct = {'e': 1, 'h': 1, 'l': 2, 'o': 1} and now i run in terminal >>> count_letters('hello', dct) the result would be {'e': 2, 'h': 2, 'l': 4, 'o': 2}

Comment: Are you allowed to use `collections.Counter`?

Comment: no I am not allowed, sorry @chrisz

Comment: @chrisz i have edited to clarify the difference

Comment: Be cautious about setting a mutable default value for the dictionary argument, see:  [“Least Astonishment” and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Pandas, you can use `value_counts()`:

```
import pandas as pd

word = "hello"
letters = [letter for letter in word]
pd.Series(letters).value_counts().to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'e': 1, 'h': 1, 'l': 2, 'o': 1}
```

Otherwise, use `dict` and `list` comprehensions:

```
letter_ct = {letter:0 for letter in word}
for letter in word:
    letter_ct[letter] += 1
letter_ct
```

Comment: sorry is there an alternative way because I do not know Pandas as I am not that good at python and have just started to learn it. but thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

You can use pythons defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict

def word_counter(word):
   word_dict = defaultdict(int)

   for letter in word:
      word_dict[letter] += 1

    return(word_dict)

print(word_counter('hello'))
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'h': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 2, 'o': 1})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def count_freqs(string, dictionary={}):
  for letter in string:
    if letter not in dictionary:
      dictionary[letter] = 1
    else:
      dictionary[letter] += 1
  return dictionary
```

Comment: learn from this @Aran-Fey

Comment: You'll find that this [doesn't work correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) because of the way you set `dictionary`'s default value.